# MySQL read replica on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

I've recently started using AWS Aurora to take advantage of the improvements over standard MySQL. I have a REST API running that connects either to the main cluster endpoint, or the read endpoint if the request will only perform `SELECT`s. Obviously I want to test this locally so that I don't mark any routes as read only if they're not.

I installed mysql with Homebrew and have it running as a service. What I need to do now is have another mysql instance running on a different port, and then set up read replication between my original instance and the new one.

Does anyone have any idea how I go about this?